# DNS lookups for hostnames ask for inventory_hostname.domain.tld

Tags: ansible

when I try to execute my playbook to connect to a Cisco switch, I only get the error message:
`ssh connect failed: Failed to resolve hostname inventory_hostname`

ATM I use Ansible 2.14 installed at my homedir.

All informations are sanityzed.
Please assume:
`1.1.1.1 = ansible host 2.2.2.2 = DNS server 3.3.3.3 = switch to connect domain.local = search domain that is automaticaly appended by the ansible host`

Direct SSH:

```
$ssh ansible@sw1
Password: 
Login successful.
sw1#
```

Inventory:

```
$ansible-inventory -i hosts.yml --host sw1
{
    "ansible_become": true,
    "ansible_become_method": "enable",
    "ansible_connection": "ansible.netcommon.network_cli",
    "ansible_fqdn": "sw1.domain.local",
    "ansible_host": "3.3.3.3",
    "ansible_hostname": "sw1",
    "ansible_network_os": "cisco.ios.ios",
    "ansible_password": "**************",
    "ansible_user": "ansible"
}
```

Example playbook (any other gives the same result):

```
---
# Playbook for sw1

- name: Show Version
  hosts: sw1
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: print inventory_hostname
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
    - name: print ansible_hostname
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: ansible_hostname
    - name: print ansible_fqdn
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: ansible_fqdn
    - name: print ansible_ssh_host
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: ansible_ssh_host

    - name: Print output
      debug:
        msg: "{{ansible_facts}}"

    - name: Gather all legacy facts
      cisco.ios.ios_facts:
        gather_subset: all

    - name: Print output
      debug:
        msg: "{{ansible_facts}}"
```

Playbook Output:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts.yml show_facts_sw1.yml

PLAY [Show Facts] *************************

TASK [print inventory_hostname] ***********
ok: [sw1] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "sw1"
}

TASK [print ansible_hostname] *************
ok: [sw1] => {
    "ansible_hostname": "sw1"
}

TASK [print ansible_fqdn] *****************
ok: [sw1] => {
    "ansible_fqdn": "sw1.domain.local"
}

TASK [print ansible_ssh_host] *************
ok: [sw1] => {
    "ansible_ssh_host": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [Print output] **********************
ok: [sw1] => {
    "msg": {}
}

TASK [Gather all legacy facts] **********
fatal: [sw1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ssh connection failed: ssh connect        failed: Failed to resolve hostname inventory_hostname (Temporary failure in name resolution)"}

PLAY RECAP *******************
sw1          : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

(I set the ansible_ssh_host variable at the inventory to the IP addresse with the same result)

```
tcpdump port 53
10:56:56.409051 IP 1.1.1.1.34980 > 2.2.2.2.53: 41061+ A? inventory_hostname.domain.local. (43)
10:56:56.409076 IP 1.1.1.1.34980 > 2.2.2.2.53: 40545+ AAAA? inventory_hostname.domain.local. (43)
10:56:56.409867 IP 2.2.2.2.53 > 1.1.1.1.34980: 41061 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (92)
10:56:56.409906 IP 2.2.2.2.53 > 1.1.1.1.34980: 40545 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (92)
```

(The string "inventory_hostname" is original as it get shown by tcpdump)

```
Versions:
ansible --version
ansible [core 2.14.1]
  config file = /home/user/network/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/user/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] (/usr/binpython3)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

I changed every hostname variable to IP address and back with no result.
I try to switch DNS resolving off by `ansible_host_dns_name: false` at group and host variable.
I try to find a solution online, but I only find explanations about special variables at ansible.

Does anyone have an idea what went wrong here?
I try to solve that problem since days and can't find out if I made something wrong or if there is something inside ansible.

This is not a DNS problem.
I can resolve all hostnames and get the right IP back.

I hope that I post enough informations.
If something isn't there please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @isilia that doesn't seem relevant; `ansible_ssh_host` isn't being used here (the task that attempts to print it out shows `VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED`). The output at the beginning of the question shows that `ansible_host` is already set.

Comment: @belarion - Try changing gather_facts to yes and then try to re-run the playbook

Comment: @isilia: This variable was filled with the IP address with same result. At the moment it's intended to be empty, cause it has no effect. The facts can't gathered at cisco devices. So its normal that this is set to no. Intention is to gather facts by the module cisco.ios.ios_facts later at the playbook. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @belarion..run the playbook with -vvvv option to capture detailed log and update in the question

Comment: Also please update your ansible.cfg file in the question as well

Comment: Make sure that you're running the latest versions of the involved collections; there was a common plugin implementation mistake that would result in untemplated usage of the string `inventory_hostname` in some circumstances, but AFAIK it's been fixed everywhere it cropped up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to isilia and flowerysong for your replys.

I don't know to run an update of installed collections so I choose to force install them:

```
$ansible-galaxy collection install cisco.ios --force
```

and

```
$ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.netcommon community.network --force
```

with installs without errors.

This is my ansible.cfg file without comments:

```
[defaults]
inventory      = ./hosts.yml
host_key_checking = False
remote_user = root
vault_password_file = ~/HIDDEN
ansible_managed = "### %n## %n# This file is managed by Ansible.%n# Changing is not recomended%n# This file will be overwritten!%n %n# template: {file} %n# date: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %n# user: {uid} %n# host: {host} %n## %n###"
[inventory]
enable_plugins = netbox.netbox.nb_inventory, auto, host_list, yaml, ini, toml, script
```

All other settings are at their defaults.

This is the playbook run with verbosity 4.

```
$ansible-playbook -i hosts.yml show_facts_sw1.yml -vvvv

ansible-playbook [core 2.14.1]
  config file = /home/user/network/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
Using /home/user/network/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
Loading collection netbox.netbox from /home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/netbox/netbox
host_list declined parsing /home/user/network/hosts_static.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /home/user/network/hosts_static.yml inventory source with yaml plugin
Loading collection cisco.ios from /home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/cisco/ios
redirecting (type: action) cisco.ios.ios_facts to cisco.ios.ios
Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
PLAYBOOK: show_facts_sw1.yml 
Positional arguments: show_facts_sw1.yml
verbosity: 4
remote_user: ansible
connection: smart
timeout: 10
become_method: sudo
tags: ('all',)
inventory: ('/home/user/network/hosts.yml',)
forks: 5
1 plays in show_facts_sw1.yml
PLAY [Show Version] 
Trying secret FileVaultSecret(filename='HIDDEN') for vault_id=default
Trying secret FileVaultSecret(filename='HIDDEN') for vault_id=default
TASK [print inventory_hostname] 
task path: /home/user/network/show_facts_sw1.yml:9
Loading collection ansible.netcommon from /home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/netcommon
redirecting (type: become) ansible.builtin.enable to ansible.netcommon.enable
<3.3.3.3> attempting to start connection
<3.3.3.3> using connection plugin ansible.netcommon.network_cli
Found ansible-connection at path /usr/bin/ansible-connection
<3.3.3.3> local domain socket does not exist, starting it
<3.3.3.3> control socket path is /home/user/.ansible/pc/973a0929c7
<3.3.3.3> local domain socket listeners started successfully
<3.3.3.3> loaded cliconf plugin ansible_collections.cisco.ios.plugins.cliconf.ios from path /home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/cisco/ios/plugins/cliconf/ios.py for network_os cisco.ios.ios
<3.3.3.3> ssh type is set to auto
<3.3.3.3> autodetecting ssh_type
<3.3.3.3> ssh type is now set to libssh
<3.3.3.3> 
<3.3.3.3> local domain socket path is /home/user/.ansible/pc/973a0929c7
ok: [sw1] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "sw1"
}
TASK [print ansible_hostname] 
task path: /home/user/network/show_facts_sw1.yml:12
Loading collection ansible.netcommon from /home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/netcommon
redirecting (type: become) ansible.builtin.enable to ansible.netcommon.enable
<3.3.3.3> attempting to start connection
<3.3.3.3> using connection plugin ansible.netcommon.network_cli
Found ansible-connection at path /usr/bin/ansible-connection
<3.3.3.3> found existing local domain socket, using it!
<3.3.3.3> updating play_context for connection
<3.3.3.3> 
<3.3.3.3> local domain socket path is /home/user/.ansible/pc/973a0929c7
ok: [sw1] => {
    "ansible_hostname": "sw1"
}
TASK [print ansible_fqdn] 
task path: /home/user/network/show_facts_sw1.yml:15
Loading collection ansible.netcommon from /home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/netcommon
redirecting (type: become) ansible.builtin.enable to ansible.netcommon.enable
<3.3.3.3> attempting to start connection
<3.3.3.3> using connection plugin ansible.netcommon.network_cli
Found ansible-connection at path /usr/bin/ansible-connection
<3.3.3.3> found existing local domain socket, using it!
<3.3.3.3> updating play_context for connection
<3.3.3.3> 
<3.3.3.3> local domain socket path is /home/user/.ansible/pc/973a0929c7
ok: [sw1] => {
    "ansible_fqdn": "sw1.ee.psi"
}
TASK [Print output] 
task path: /home/user/network/show_facts_sw1.yml:22
Loading collection ansible.netcommon from /home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/netcommon
redirecting (type: become) ansible.builtin.enable to ansible.netcommon.enable
<3.3.3.3> attempting to start connection
<3.3.3.3> using connection plugin ansible.netcommon.network_cli
Found ansible-connection at path /usr/bin/ansible-connection
<3.3.3.3> found existing local domain socket, using it!
<3.3.3.3> updating play_context for connection
<3.3.3.3> 
<3.3.3.3> local domain socket path is /home/user/.ansible/pc/973a0929c7
ok: [sw1] => {
    "msg": {}
}
redirecting (type: action) cisco.ios.ios_facts to cisco.ios.ios
Loading collection ansible.netcommon from /home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/netcommon
TASK [Gather all legacy facts] 
task path: /home/user/network/show_facts_sw1.yml:26
redirecting (type: become) ansible.builtin.enable to ansible.netcommon.enable
<3.3.3.3> attempting to start connection
<3.3.3.3> using connection plugin ansible.netcommon.network_cli
Found ansible-connection at path /usr/bin/ansible-connection
<3.3.3.3> found existing local domain socket, using it!
<3.3.3.3> updating play_context for connection
<3.3.3.3> 
<3.3.3.3> local domain socket path is /home/user/.ansible/pc/973a0929c7
redirecting (type: action) cisco.ios.ios_facts to cisco.ios.ios
redirecting (type: action) cisco.ios.ios_facts to cisco.ios.ios
<3.3.3.3> ANSIBLE_NETWORK_IMPORT_MODULES: enabled
<3.3.3.3> ANSIBLE_NETWORK_IMPORT_MODULES: found cisco.ios.ios_facts  at /home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/cisco/ios/plugins/modules/ios_facts.py
<3.3.3.3> ANSIBLE_NETWORK_IMPORT_MODULES: running cisco.ios.ios_facts
<3.3.3.3> ANSIBLE_NETWORK_IMPORT_MODULES: complete
The full traceback is:
  File "/home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/netcommon/plugins/module_utils/network/common/network.py", line 233, in get_capabilities
    capabilities = Connection(module._socket_path).get_capabilities()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/module_utils/connection.py", line 200, in __rpc__
    raise ConnectionError(to_text(msg, errors='surrogate_then_replace'), code=code)
fatal: [sw1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "available_network_resources": false,
            "gather_network_resources": null,
            "gather_subset": [
                "all"
            ]
        }
    },
    "msg": "ssh connection failed: ssh connect failed: Failed to resolve hostname inventory_hostname (Temporary failure in name resolution)"
}
```

Comment: I ported the settings and playbook to a diffrerent ansible host at a testing environment. The only difference is there is ansible 2.13 installed. The playbook is running successfull there. So I think there is a problem with version 2.14.

Answer (score 0):

After some more reading and experimenting I removed Ansible from my host and reinstalled version 2.12 witch is working.